# What preposition to use with the word "ignorant"?

Tags: prepositions

"It’s ignorant **from** you to say that" or "It’s ignorant **of** you to say that"

Comment: Not from. Of, or for.

Comment: Prepositions can be a tricky aspect of the English language; native speakers may even disagree on which sounds best. (For example, someone might prefer "disagree *about* which sounds best".) A useful tip can be to check Google: "ignorant of you" returns 100× the hits from "ignorant from you".

Comment: Here you get the answer to your question- https://learnersdictionary.com/qa/What-preposition-should-be-used-after-ignorant#:~:text=The%20adjective%20ignorant%2C%20which%20means,ignorant%20of%2Fabout%20the%20facts.

Answer (score 1):

"It's ignorant of you to say that"
or
"It's ignorant for you to say that"